# Why wrapper class is not working in Vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and now working on basic css. I used `.wrapper` class to wrap children with 1200px, but it isn't working.. why?

**Example.vue**

```
<template>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
$color: red;
header {
  height: 48px;
  background: $color;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

Wrapper div doesn't wrap child element `p` , I don't know why this isn't working even if it is very simple example...

[image: Edit elated-kilby-xg37n]

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't wrap? Can you show us what exactly is going on? Also, this is very likely not a VueJS problem :)

Comment: @Terry If it works well, `p` element should have `width: 1200px`, but it increases more than 1200px

Comment: Share a minimal, concrete and verifiable example, because based on the code above there is no reason why `p` will overflow its container.

Comment: @Terry I shared

Comment: If you inspect your element, `<p>` does have a width of 1200px. I guess you think it is not wrapping properly is because the red background is assigned to `<header>`?

Comment: When I change 1200px to 300px, it works properly, then it means that browser width is different from wrapper width. why?

Comment: Oh.. I solved, I had zoomed, sorry..

Comment: @HaramBae please consider closing this question or answering the question yourself if it is solved.